# How to create mosaic video with both audio and video streams: FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I used the following line to create a mosaic video output with four videos each starting at a particular location and time. Following is the line of code I used

```
ffmpeg -i lead_1.mp4 -i lead_2.mp4 -i lead_3.mp4 -i lead_4.mp4 
-filter_complex 
"color=s=1280x720:c=black [base]; 
[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale= 640x360 [upperleft1]; 
[1:v] setpts=PTS+35/TB, scale=640x360 [lowerright1]; 
[2:v] setpts=PTS+87/TB, scale=640x360 [upperleft2]; 
[3:v] setpts=PTS+183/TB, scale=640x360 [lowerright2]; 
[base][upperleft1] overlay=1 [tmp1]; 
[tmp1][lowerright1] overlay=1:x=640:y=360 [tmp2]; 
[tmp2] [upperleft2] overlay=1 [tmp3]; 
[tmp3][lowerright2] overlay=1:x=640:y=360" 

-c:v libx264 lead_1_2_3_4.mp4
```

So the output file does not contain the audio streams from all the videos. I am new to FFMPEG so can someone suggest how do I get even the audio streams of all the input files in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Add the [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) and [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i lead_1.mp4 -i lead_2.mp4 -i lead_3.mp4 -i lead_4.mp4 
-filter_complex 
"color=s=1280x720:c=black [base]; 
[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale= 640x360 [upperleft1]; 
[1:v] setpts=PTS+35/TB, scale=640x360 [lowerright1]; 
[2:v] setpts=PTS+87/TB, scale=640x360 [upperleft2]; 
[3:v] setpts=PTS+183/TB, scale=640x360 [lowerright2]; 
[base][upperleft1] overlay[tmp1]; 
[tmp1][lowerright1] overlay=x=overlay_w:y=overlay_h [tmp2]; 
[tmp2] [upperleft2] overlay [tmp3]; 
[tmp3][lowerright2] overlay=x=overlay_w:y=overlay_h[v];
[1]adelay=35s:all=1[a1];
[2]adelay=87s:all=1[a2];
[3]adelay=183s:all=1[a3];
[0:a][a1][a2][a3]amix=inputs=4[a]" 
-map "[v]" -map "[a]"
-c:v libx264 lead_1_2_3_4.mp4
```

If your `ffmpeg` is old use `adelay=35000|35000` instead (assuming stereo input).

Comment: Hi,
So it gave me an error, I tried adding
-c:a aac
after libx264, but even that edit did not work for some reason

Comment: @DhulipalaChandrasekhar You should always provide the actual error instead of just mentioning that you got an error. Without the actual error I am unable to suggest anything. It would be most helpful if you provide the command you used and the complete log from the command. This will allow you to receive an answer much faster. You can use a pastebin site and provide a link in a comment.